# about "[to be] so unlikely to become common as to be innocuous"

Tags: meaning, grammar

The following sentence is from Bertrand Russell. I would like to know if in the emboldened part the [equative structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equative) *not so ... as* is used or it's another structure with a different meaning.

> ... they will conclude that a new belief is probably either an advance, or **so unlikely to become common as to be innocuous**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, should I delete my post if I realize it's a duplicate?

Comment: Don't worry about it; it should be closed in the course of time. Read the other question and answers; there may be some nuance that is different. I'm not sure how common the term 'equative structure' is in the literature.

Comment: Thanks, @EdwinAshworth. I've seen the term 'equative' in an advanced grammar book of Oxford.  'equative structure' also seems to [be used](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22equative+structure%22&client=ubuntu&hs=FAo&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFxubxw_3aAhVlGZoKHSESBdAQ_AUIDigA&biw=1325&bih=670).

Comment: The statementfrom [Enhanced Theme in English ...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eX8dAQAAIAAJ&q=%22equative+structure%22&dq=%22equative+structure%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi54orZxf3aAhXkLMAKHVIrDLkQ6AEIXzAJ) 'Halliday (1967b) treats the enhanced theme construction as an equative structure.' would seem to indicate that there isn't a consensus on this terminology / analysis.